# Para que serve o operador &?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var n = prompt("Digite um numero");
if(n & 1){
    alert("Impar");
} else {
    alert("Par");
}
alert(n);
```

Esse bloco de código é muito simples, mas o foco é neste operador `&`. Para que ele serve? e no código em cima ele está fazendo oque `n & 1`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Segundo o **MDN**:

> Operadores bit-a-bit são são operadores tratados como sequência de 32
>   bits ( zeros e uns ), preferencialmente como decimal, hexadecimal, ou
>   números octais. Por exemplo, o número decimal 9 tinha como
>   representação binária de 1001. Operadores bit-a-bit realizam as
>   operações em tais representações binárias, mas retornam valores
>   numéricos no padrão Javascript

.

```
console.log(5 & 13); // 0101 & 1101 = 0101
// expected output: 5;

console.log(parseInt("0101",2) & parseInt("1101",2));
// expected output: 5;

console.log(5 & 13 & 3); // 0101 & 1101 & 0011 = 0001
// expected output: 1;

console.log(5 | 13); // 0101 | 1101 = 1101
// expected output: 13
```

....Operador......  Uso............     Descrição

Bitwise AND........ a & b...      Retorna 1 em cada posição de bit para à qual o

.........................................  bit correspondente de ambos eram 1s.

Fonte:  [Bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)